# Arraylist stores same object multiple times?

Tags: android, object, arraylist, cursor

I don't know why Arraylist Stores similar objects.
kindly help me. Thank you in advance.
i know there is some thing wrong with the logic of looping cursor or storing in Arraylist.
The array lists are defined by this way,

```
public ArrayList<Object> results=new ArrayList<Object>();

public ArrayList<String> arrTemp=new ArrayList<String>();
```

following is my code:

```
db = getReadableDatabase();// /////--->Here database is opened
        cursor = db.rawQuery("Select symbol,date,open,high,Low,close from testTBL;", null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                arrTemp.clear();

                    arrTemp.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("symbol")));
                    arrTemp.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
                    arrTemp.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("open")));
                    arrTemp.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("high")));
                    arrTemp.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Low")));
                    arrTemp.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("close")));

                Log.v("arrayTemp inside while loop", ""+arrTemp);

                results.add(arrTemp);
                Log.v("Results stored", ""+results);
            }

                Log.v("Final Results", ""+results);


            cursor.close();
        }

            db.close();
```

Following is Logcat output:

```
03-03 02:35:38.614: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [ACC, 25-Feb-13, 1,302.00, 1,321.00, 1,293.05, 1,305.60]
03-03 02:35:38.614: V/Results stored(337): [[ACC, 25-Feb-13, 1,302.00, 1,321.00, 1,293.05, 1,305.60]]
03-03 02:35:38.624: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [ACC, 22-Feb-13, 1,300.05, 1,308.05, 1,295.00, 1,300.95]
03-03 02:35:38.624: V/Results stored(337): [[ACC, 22-Feb-13, 1,300.05, 1,308.05, 1,295.00, 1,300.95], [ACC, 22-Feb-13, 1,300.05, 1,308.05, 1,295.00, 1,300.95]]
03-03 02:35:38.649: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [WIPRO, 25-Feb-13, 416.2, 425.8, 416.2, 419.1]
03-03 02:35:38.649: V/Results stored(337): [[WIPRO, 25-Feb-13, 416.2, 425.8, 416.2, 419.1], [WIPRO, 25-Feb-13, 416.2, 425.8, 416.2, 419.1], [WIPRO, 25-Feb-13, 416.2, 425.8, 416.2, 419.1]]
03-03 02:35:38.649: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [WIPRO, 22-Feb-13, 404.5, 418.45, 403.15, 415.95]
03-03 02:35:38.654: V/Results stored(337): [[WIPRO, 22-Feb-13, 404.5, 418.45, 403.15, 415.95], [WIPRO, 22-Feb-13, 404.5, 418.45, 403.15, 415.95], [WIPRO, 22-Feb-13, 404.5, 418.45, 403.15, 415.95], [WIPRO, 22-Feb-13, 404.5, 418.45, 403.15, 415.95]]
03-03 02:35:38.654: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [ICICI, 25-Feb-13, 1,099.00, 1,101.85, 1,081.20, 1,093.90]
03-03 02:35:38.654: V/Results stored(337): [[ICICI, 25-Feb-13, 1,099.00, 1,101.85, 1,081.20, 1,093.90], [ICICI, 25-Feb-13, 1,099.00, 1,101.85, 1,081.20, 1,093.90], [ICICI, 25-Feb-13, 1,099.00, 1,101.85, 1,081.20, 1,093.90], [ICICI, 25-Feb-13, 1,099.00, 1,101.85, 1,081.20, 1,093.90], [ICICI, 25-Feb-13, 1,099.00, 1,101.85, 1,081.20, 1,093.90]]
03-03 02:35:38.654: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [ICICI, 22-Feb-13, 1,077.05, 1,099.00, 1,077.05, 1,092.55]
03-03 02:35:38.654: V/Results stored(337): [[ICICI, 22-Feb-13, 1,077.05, 1,099.00, 1,077.05, 1,092.55], [ICICI, 22-Feb-13, 1,077.05, 1,099.00, 1,077.05, 1,092.55], [ICICI, 22-Feb-13, 1,077.05, 1,099.00, 1,077.05, 1,092.55], [ICICI, 22-Feb-13, 1,077.05, 1,099.00, 1,077.05, 1,092.55], [ICICI, 22-Feb-13, 1,077.05, 1,099.00, 1,077.05, 1,092.55], [ICICI, 22-Feb-13, 1,077.05, 1,099.00, 1,077.05, 1,092.55]]
03-03 02:35:38.666: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [TATA MOTORS, 25-Feb-13, 296.8, 301.25, 295.1, 299.15]
03-03 02:35:38.666: V/Results stored(337): [[TATA MOTORS, 25-Feb-13, 296.8, 301.25, 295.1, 299.15], [TATA MOTORS, 25-Feb-13, 296.8, 301.25, 295.1, 299.15], [TATA MOTORS, 25-Feb-13, 296.8, 301.25, 295.1, 299.15], [TATA MOTORS, 25-Feb-13, 296.8, 301.25, 295.1, 299.15], [TATA MOTORS, 25-Feb-13, 296.8, 301.25, 295.1, 299.15], [TATA MOTORS, 25-Feb-13, 296.8, 301.25, 295.1, 299.15], [TATA MOTORS, 25-Feb-13, 296.8, 301.25, 295.1, 299.15]]
03-03 02:35:38.666: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [TATA MOTORS, 22-Feb-13, 294.95, 297.55, 289.85, 292.9]
03-03 02:35:38.666: V/Results stored(337): [[TATA MOTORS, 22-Feb-13, 294.95, 297.55, 289.85, 292.9], [TATA MOTORS, 22-Feb-13, 294.95, 297.55, 289.85, 292.9], [TATA MOTORS, 22-Feb-13, 294.95, 297.55, 289.85, 292.9], [TATA MOTORS, 22-Feb-13, 294.95, 297.55, 289.85, 292.9], [TATA MOTORS, 22-Feb-13, 294.95, 297.55, 289.85, 292.9], [TATA MOTORS, 22-Feb-13, 294.95, 297.55, 289.85, 292.9], [TATA MOTORS, 22-Feb-13, 294.95, 297.55, 289.85, 292.9], [TATA MOTORS, 22-Feb-13, 294.95, 297.55, 289.85, 292.9]]
03-03 02:35:38.674: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [NESTLE, 25-Feb-13, 4,606.40, 4,689.90, 4,600.00, 4,654.55]
03-03 02:35:38.674: V/Results stored(337): [[NESTLE, 25-Feb-13, 4,606.40, 4,689.90, 4,600.00, 4,654.55], [NESTLE, 25-Feb-13, 4,606.40, 4,689.90, 4,600.00, 4,654.55], [NESTLE, 25-Feb-13, 4,606.40, 4,689.90, 4,600.00, 4,654.55], [NESTLE, 25-Feb-13, 4,606.40, 4,689.90, 4,600.00, 4,654.55], [NESTLE, 25-Feb-13, 4,606.40, 4,689.90, 4,600.00, 4,654.55], [NESTLE, 25-Feb-13, 4,606.40, 4,689.90, 4,600.00, 4,654.55], [NESTLE, 25-Feb-13, 4,606.40, 4,689.90, 4,600.00, 4,654.55], [NESTLE, 25-Feb-13, 4,606.40, 4,689.90, 4,600.00, 4,654.55], [NESTLE, 25-Feb-13, 4,606.40, 4,689.90, 4,600.00, 4,654.55]]
03-03 02:35:38.674: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [NESTLE, 22-Feb-13, 4,644.65, 4,747.70, 4,608.00, 4,629.10]
03-03 02:35:38.684: V/Results stored(337): [[NESTLE, 22-Feb-13, 4,644.65, 4,747.70, 4,608.00, 4,629.10], [NESTLE, 22-Feb-13, 4,644.65, 4,747.70, 4,608.00, 4,629.10], [NESTLE, 22-Feb-13, 4,644.65, 4,747.70, 4,608.00, 4,629.10], [NESTLE, 22-Feb-13, 4,644.65, 4,747.70, 4,608.00, 4,629.10], [NESTLE, 22-Feb-13, 4,644.65, 4,747.70, 4,608.00, 4,629.10], [NESTLE, 22-Feb-13, 4,644.65, 4,747.70, 4,608.00, 4,629.10], [NESTLE, 22-Feb-13, 4,644.65, 4,747.70, 4,608.00, 4,629.10], [NESTLE, 22-Feb-13, 4,644.65, 4,747.70, 4,608.00, 4,629.10], [NESTLE, 22-Feb-13, 4,644.65, 4,747.70, 4,608.00, 4,629.10], [NESTLE, 22-Feb-13, 4,644.65, 4,747.70, 4,608.00, 4,629.10]]
03-03 02:35:38.684: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85]
03-03 02:35:38.684: V/Results stored(337): [[RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85], [RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85], [RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85], [RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85], [RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85], [RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85], [RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85], [RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85], [RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85], [RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85], [RANBAXY, 25-Feb-13, 422, 435, 422, 433.85]]
03-03 02:35:38.694: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55]
03-03 02:35:38.704: V/Results stored(337): [[RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55], [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55], [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55], [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55], [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55], [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55], [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55], [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55], [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55], [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55], [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55], [RANBAXY, 22-Feb-13, 412.5, 417, 411.1, 413.55]]
03-03 02:35:38.704: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35]
03-03 02:35:38.704: V/Results stored(337): [[REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35], [REDDY, 25-Feb-13, 1,805.00, 1,814.00, 1,791.55, 1,804.35]]
03-03 02:35:38.714: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20]
03-03 02:35:38.724: V/Results stored(337): [[REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20], [REDDY, 22-Feb-13, 1,815.00, 1,824.95, 1,790.10, 1,816.20]]
03-03 02:35:38.724: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45]
03-03 02:35:38.735: V/Results stored(337): [[HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45], [HDFC, 25-Feb-13, 663.25, 665.2, 654.1, 656.45]]
03-03 02:35:38.735: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3]
03-03 02:35:38.744: V/Results stored(337): [[HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3], [HDFC, 22-Feb-13, 662.2, 666.4, 657.55, 659.3]]
03-03 02:35:38.744: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10]
03-03 02:35:38.754: V/Results stored(337): [[MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10], [MARUTI, 25-Feb-13, 1,442.00, 1,459.90, 1,438.25, 1,444.10]]
03-03 02:35:38.764: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40]
03-03 02:35:38.774: V/Results stored(337): [[MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40], [MARUTI, 22-Feb-13, 1,463.40, 1,467.00, 1,430.10, 1,438.40]]
03-03 02:35:38.774: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7]
03-03 02:35:38.785: V/Results stored(337): [[HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7], [HUL, 25-Feb-13, 456.05, 457.8, 450, 451.7]]
03-03 02:35:38.785: V/arrayTemp inside while loop(337): [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4]
03-03 02:35:38.804: V/Results stored(337): [[HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4]]
03-03 02:35:38.814: V/Final Results(337): [[HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4], [HUL, 22-Feb-13, 467, 467.15, 454, 455.4]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour occures because you aren't storing a copy of `arrTemp` in `results`, but only a reference. You are always operating on the same object, not separate lists. Now every time `arrTemp.clear()` is called in the while loop, you are actually clearing the reference stored in `results`. Then you add new values to `arrTemp` and then add another reference to `arrTemp` to `results` again, resulting in two (three, four...) identical references to the same list in `results`.

A simple solution would be to not declare `arrTemp` as a member variable, but within the while-loop like this:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
{
    ArrayList<String> arrTemp = new ArrayList<String>();

    //...
    // fill arrTemp
    //...

    results.add(arrTemp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a POJO class with the table structure??
Like

```
Class TestClass{
private String symbol;
private String date;
//etc
}
```

Now create an arraylist to contain this type of object like this

```
public ArrayList<TestClass> results=new ArrayList<TestClass>();
```